# Referencing F# code in android project

Tags: c#, android, f#, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

I'm doing a project where i am supposed to write an android application that uses a code-base of f# code. In doing so i am running into some problems regarding referencing this f# code in my android project.

I've been googling and it tells me that the f# code has to be in a PCL project that is referenced by the android project.
I've done this, but the android project is still not able to recognise the namespaces and files declared in the other project.

I have a namespace called `NimGame.Core` where most of my .fs files are located.
An example are shown in the picture below of my event queue module that is clearly located in NimGame.Core. IT can also be seen in my references that i have referenced the PCL project (NimGameCore) in my android project (NimGame).
[image: Example of fsharp code]

But when i am trying to use the fsharp files in my c# code it doesn't show up.
[image: Example2]

Any suggestions as to what can be causing this?

Comment: To increase visibility of your question, try adding more specific tags - my guess is that adding "xamarin" tag will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was [a bug in Xamarin Studio](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=46457) and [MonoDevelp](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/pull/1657/files) which prevented IntelliSense from working when F# project was referenced from C# project. Additionally, F# types in C# code were underlined with red line.

The bug was fixed, so upgrading you IDE should solve the problem.

Comment: It's not that IntelliSense doesn't work, it was just my way of showing that it doesn't recognize the namespace. I've updated everything that i can on my IDE.

Comment: @KasperLederballeSørensen What IDE are you using (Xamarin Studio or Mono Develop)? Which version? What does it mean that the namespace is "not recognized"? Are you getting a compile error? What's the error message and what is the exact C# code that gives you that error?

Comment: Xamarin Studio version 6.2 build 1821. What is means that it is not recognised is that when trying to type in `using NimGame.Core;` it doesn't know what that is and just says that 'using directive is unnecessary'. I haven't tried to compile it or go further with it, as i won't be able to. I need the f# code to be used as it is the code base and main functionality for the program.

Comment: @KasperLederballeSørensen please try to compile it anyway and look into compile output. You can also try disabling Xamarin Studio's plugins as they might cause conflicts. If you're pretty sure that it's a bug, please open a bug in Xamarin Studio's issue tracker.

Comment: I figured out that the reason that i could not be seen was because the referenced project was not succesfully compiling in another file. I just figured that the ones that there were no errors in would be visible and referenced. Thanks a lot for the help.